# Keras ValueError: Error when checking model target (CNN)

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

The algorithm is designed to describe products. This part recognizes the colors of clothes from images (14 output values)    however, it still returns the following error

Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays 
that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. 
Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 14 
arrays.
```

part of the code:

```
TRAIN_LABELS_FILE = "train/labels.txt"
VAL_LABELS_FILE = "val/labels.txt"
TEST_LABELS_FILE = "test/labels.txt"
COLOR_FILE = "names.txt"

# Specify image size
IMG_WIDTH = 128
IMG_HEIGHT = 128
CHANNELS = 3

color = pd.read_csv(COLOR_FILE)
color = color.T
color_list = list(color.iloc[0])
color_list.insert(0,'beige')
color_list.insert(0,'path')

train = pd.read_csv(TRAIN_LABELS_FILE,sep=" ",names=color_list, dtype="str")
val = pd.read_csv(VAL_LABELS_FILE,sep=" ",names=color_list, dtype="str")

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
BATCH_SIZE = 4
#directory = os.path.dirname(path)

# Add Image augmentation to our generator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=360,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split=0.15,
                                   #preprocessing_function=preprocess_image, 
                                   rescale=1 / 128.)

# Use the dataframe to define train and validation generators
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(train, 
                                                    x_col='path', 
                                                    y_col=color_list[1:],
                                                    directory='train',
                                                    target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode="multi_output", 
                                                    subset='training')

val_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(val, 
                                                  x_col='path', 
                                                  y_col=color_list[1:],
                                                  directory='val',
                                                  target_size=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                                  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                  class_mode="multi_output",
                                                  subset='validation')

from efficientnet import EfficientNetB5
effnet = EfficientNetB5(input_shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, CHANNELS),
                          weights='imagenet',
                          include_top=False)

def build_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(effnet)
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
    print(model.summary())
    return model

# Initialize model
model = build_model()

# Begin training
model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=35,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    validation_steps = val_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE)
```

input shape is defined in the first layer 'effnet' so I don't know why an error occurs.

I also tried to convert the data to a numpy array but the effect is the same.

Dataframe train: sth.

```
      Path    black  grey  green blue   etc....
0  12345.jpg    1      0       1  0
1  12345.jpg    0      0       1  0
2  12345.jpg    1      0       0  1
3  12345.jpg    0      1       0  1
4  12345.jpg    0      0       1  1
5  12345.jpg    0      0       1  1
```

Comment: What does your dataframe look like?

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y_train (ground truth labels) in your model for each image should be a single array of 14 elements [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,...], but looks like you are passing 14 different arrays for each image. Change the shape of y_train (y_col) in your code. Also, you are storing it in a list, convert it to numpy array as the model expects.

I believe that your data is stored as pandas dataframe. In that case, drop the first column `df.drop('Path', axis=1, inplace=True)`. Then you can convert to numpy array as `y_train = df.to_numpy()`. This will give you the target in correct shape. Give this in fit method for training.

Also, note that `df.to_numpy()` works only if you are using the latest pandas version. For old versions, you can use `df.values` to convert the dataframe to numpy array.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `class_mode="other"` instead of `class_mode="multi_output"` in both `train_generator` and `val_generator`. [Ref: [multi-label-classification-with-keras-imagedatagenerator](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24)]

Furthermore, Since it's a multi-label classification problem, you should use `sigmoid` activation function in the output layer of your model. You should also use `binary_crossentropy` loss while compiling your model as for each target class you need to determine whether the input belongs to that class or not.

```
model.add(Dense(14, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: yes, but the one "item" could be red and yellow, black etc. (like multicolor)

Comment: yes, `class_mode="categorical"` supports multi-label. please check out the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about it, but here I have a problem I don't understand -  ```If class_mode = "categorical", y_col = column values ​​must be type string, list or tuple.``` When I define y_col this is a list and the error remains

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/135) you should use `class_mode='other'`. If your labels were in a single column then `class_mode = "categorical"` could work. you can find a perfect example [here](https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24). Also updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. everything work. But in this case metrics can't be accuracy